# SO - login with other user id

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, login

sorry for asking if it's already asked. I could not found when I search.

Here is the situation.

If I want to log-out from SO with current id, and then another guy want to log in to SO with their account, we need to clear the browser cookie and cache.

Otherwise, when I log-out and try logging in, it will automatically log in with older account.

Why is that so? Why not all session and other information are not removed when we log-out?

Comment: I have SO account. I have logged from SO and not logged into any associated or third party accounts. Still why its logged in?

Comment: @ŁukaszL. But that says to click on logout. I already did that. And then when I try to login again with other id, it automatically gets logged in to my older account. I don't want to do that. I want to login with other id without clearing my browser cache, cookies and all